# put a http:// on a string if it does not contain it else disregard string in php

Tags: php, string, boolean, href, strpos

*i'm trying to put a **http://** on a string if it does not contain it and then disregard the string if it already does the problem is it does not disregard the string if it does contain it, here is my code:*

```
if(strpos($_POST['test-website'], "http://") === false || strpos($_POST['test-website'], "https://") === false){
    $url = "http://".$_POST['test-website'];
}else
    $url = $_POST['test-website'];

//Value: test.com
//Result: http://test.com

//Value: http://test.com
//Result: http://http://test.com

//Value: https://test.com
//Result: http://https://test.com
```

Comment: strpos returns a number or false. never true.

Comment: Wether this is a typo, use `||` instead of `|` (logical and bitwise operation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `=== false` instead of `!== true`, `strpos` will never return `true`.

```
if(strpos($_POST['test-website'], "http://") === false || strpos($_POST['test-website'], "https://") === false) {
```

Comment: //Value: test.com
Result: http://test.com

//Value: http://test.com
Result: http://http://test.com

//Value: https://test.com
Result: http://https://test.com

Answer (score 0):

> strpos() Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to
>   the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset).  Returns
>   FALSE if the needle was not found.it wont return true.

```
if(strpos($_POST['test-website'], "http://") === false || strpos($_POST['test-website'], "https://") === false
```